# Buscador en Jquery

Tags: jquery

Es posible Buscar cadenas que no estén juntas con Jquery
es decir

tengo este buscador

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  (function($) {
   $('#search').keyup(function () {
    var value = reemplazarAcentos($(this).val().toLowerCase())
             var ValorBusquedaDos = new RegExp(value, 'i');
            $('#content .card').hide();
             $('#content .card').filter(function () {
               var filters = ValorBusquedaDos.test(reemplazarAcentos($(this).text()));
             return filters;
            }).show();
        })
  }(jQuery));
 });


var reemplazarAcentos=function(cadena)
{
 var chars={
  "á":"a", "é":"e", "í":"i", "ó":"o", "ú":"u",
  "à":"a", "è":"e", "ì":"i", "ò":"o", "ù":"u", "ñ":"n",
  "Á":"A", "É":"E", "Í":"I", "Ó":"O", "Ú":"U",
  "À":"A", "È":"E", "Ì":"I", "Ò":"O", "Ù":"U", "Ñ":"N"}
 var expr=/[áàéèíìóòúùñ]/ig;
 var res=cadena.replace(expr,function(e){return chars[e]});
 return res;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input id="search" type="text" />
<div id="content">
   
   <div class="card">Todo comenzó con la forja de los Grandes Anillos.</div>
   <div class="card">Tres fueron entregados a los Elfos inmortales, los más sabios y bellos de todos los seres.</div>
   <div class="card">Siete a los señores Enanos. Grandes mineros y artesanos de las cavidades montañosas.</div>
   <div class="card">Y Nueve... Nueve fueron entregados a la raza de los hombres... Que ansían por encima de todo el Poder.</div>
   <div class="card">En aquellos anillos residía el poder y la voluntad para gobernar a cada raza. Pero todos ellos fueron engañados... Pues otro Anillo más fue forjado... En la tierra de Mordor, en los fuegos del Monte del destino, el Señor Oscuro Sauron forjó en secreto el Anillo Regente para controlar a todos los demás. En ese Anillo descargó toda su crueldad, su malicia y su voluntad de dominar todo tipo de vida... </div>
   <div class="card">Un Anillo para gobernarlos a todos. Uno a uno, los pueblos libres de la Tierra Media fueron sometidos por el poder del Anillo.</div>
   <div class="card">Pero hubo algunos que resistieron. Una Última Alianza de Hombres y Elfos lucharon contra el ejército de Mordor. Y en las lomas del Monte del Destino libraron su batalla por la libertad de la Tierra Media. La victoria estaba próxima... Pero nada puede acabar con el Poder del Anillo... Y fué en aquel preciso momento, desvanecida ya toda esperanza, cuando Isildur, Hijo del Rey recurrió a la espada de su padre...</div>
   <div class="card">Sauron, el enemigo de los pueblos libres de la Tierra Media fue derrotado.</div>
   <div class="card">El Anillo llegó a manos de Isildur, que tuvo la oportunidad de destruir su mal para siempre. Pero el corazón de los hombres se corrompe con facilidad, y el Anillo de Poder goza de voluntad propia. Traicionó a Isildur hasta llevarle a la muerte.</div>
   <div class="card">Y aquellos hechos que nunca debieron caer en el olvido, se perdieron en el tiempo. La Historia se convirtió en Leyenda. La Leyenda se convirtió en Mito, y durante 2.500 años el Anillo pasó desapercibido. Hasta que cuando se presentó la ocasión encontró a un nuevo dueño... ¡Mi Tessoro! El Anillo acabó en manos de la criatura Gollum que lo ocultó en las profundidades de las Montañas Nubladas. Y allí, le consumió.</div>
```

me encuentra un palabra o varias sin problema (El Anillo acabó en manos de la criatura), quisiera saber si es posible encontrar (El acabó en manos de la criatura) omitiendo la palabra (anillo).

es decir que las palabra no sean consecutivas

Comment: Podrías si, lo suyo sería que recogas el valor que buscas y hagas primero una comparación de si existe tal cual, en caso de que no exista, sería separar la frase buscada en array, y determinar el numero de posiciones de ese array que se corresponden con arrays de los resultados posibles, lo suyo sería indicar cual sería el número minimo de coincidencias para marcarla como valida, por ejemplo: `la búsqueda del anillo` , si buscamos `la búsqueda`, serían 2 de las 4 posibles, la darías por valida? Eso ya queda a tu criterio, prueba a hacer lo que te digo y nos comentas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tal y como te indican en el comentario, puedes separar el texto de búsqueda en varias palabras, buscando 1 a 1 y en caso que no exista una en el texto, no se muestra la card. Un ejemplo sería de la siguiente manera:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
  (function ($) {
    $('#search').keyup(function () {
      var value = reemplazarAcentos($(this).val().toLowerCase())
      $('#content .card').hide();
      $('#content .card').filter(function () {
        return existText($(this).text(), value);
      }).show();
    })
  }(jQuery));
});

/**
 * Check if all words are containing into the text
 */
var existText = (text, search) => {
  // split text search in words
  var keys = search.split(' ');
  var valorBusquedaDos;
  var found = false;
  var keysLength = keys.length;
  var textWithoutAccents = reemplazarAcentos(text);

  for(var i = 0; i < keysLength; i++) {
    // search a word into the text
    valorBusquedaDos = new RegExp(keys[i], 'i');
    found = valorBusquedaDos.test(textWithoutAccents);
    // if not exist word return false
    if (!found) return false;
  }

  return true;
}

var reemplazarAcentos = function (cadena) {
  var chars = {
    "á": "a", "é": "e", "í": "i", "ó": "o", "ú": "u",
    "à": "a", "è": "e", "ì": "i", "ò": "o", "ù": "u", "ñ": "n",
    "Á": "A", "É": "E", "Í": "I", "Ó": "O", "Ú": "U",
    "À": "A", "È": "E", "Ì": "I", "Ò": "O", "Ù": "U", "Ñ": "N"
  }
  var expr = /[áàéèíìóòúùñ]/ig;
  var res = cadena.replace(expr, function (e) { return chars[e] });
  return res;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input id="search" type="text" />
<div id="content">
   
   <div class="card">Todo comenzó con la forja de los Grandes Anillos.</div>
   <div class="card">Tres fueron entregados a los Elfos inmortales, los más sabios y bellos de todos los seres.</div>
   <div class="card">Siete a los señores Enanos. Grandes mineros y artesanos de las cavidades montañosas.</div>
   <div class="card">Y Nueve... Nueve fueron entregados a la raza de los hombres... Que ansían por encima de todo el Poder.</div>
   <div class="card">En aquellos anillos residía el poder y la voluntad para gobernar a cada raza. Pero todos ellos fueron engañados... Pues otro Anillo más fue forjado... En la tierra de Mordor, en los fuegos del Monte del destino, el Señor Oscuro Sauron forjó en secreto el Anillo Regente para controlar a todos los demás. En ese Anillo descargó toda su crueldad, su malicia y su voluntad de dominar todo tipo de vida... </div>
   <div class="card">Un Anillo para gobernarlos a todos. Uno a uno, los pueblos libres de la Tierra Media fueron sometidos por el poder del Anillo.</div>
   <div class="card">Pero hubo algunos que resistieron. Una Última Alianza de Hombres y Elfos lucharon contra el ejército de Mordor. Y en las lomas del Monte del Destino libraron su batalla por la libertad de la Tierra Media. La victoria estaba próxima... Pero nada puede acabar con el Poder del Anillo... Y fué en aquel preciso momento, desvanecida ya toda esperanza, cuando Isildur, Hijo del Rey recurrió a la espada de su padre...</div>
   <div class="card">Sauron, el enemigo de los pueblos libres de la Tierra Media fue derrotado.</div>
   <div class="card">El Anillo llegó a manos de Isildur, que tuvo la oportunidad de destruir su mal para siempre. Pero el corazón de los hombres se corrompe con facilidad, y el Anillo de Poder goza de voluntad propia. Traicionó a Isildur hasta llevarle a la muerte.</div>
   <div class="card">Y aquellos hechos que nunca debieron caer en el olvido, se perdieron en el tiempo. La Historia se convirtió en Leyenda. La Leyenda se convirtió en Mito, y durante 2.500 años el Anillo pasó desapercibido. Hasta que cuando se presentó la ocasión encontró a un nuevo dueño... ¡Mi Tessoro! El Anillo acabó en manos de la criatura Gollum que lo ocultó en las profundidades de las Montañas Nubladas. Y allí, le consumió.</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sin animo de ofender, pregunta como podría hacerse, y se le responde para que pruebe, si no prueba el solo en buscar/probar su propio codigo, es más dificil que aprenda a desenvolverse, por otra parte, muy buen codigo.